# File not copied to Docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, fly

My project is an Elixir Phoenix webapp structured as follows:

```
project_root
|_Dockerfile
|_app1
|
|_app2
|  |_assets
|     |_words.txt
|
|_app3
```

where app1 has app3 as a dependency and app3 has app2 as a dependency.

My Dockerfile includes the following

```
# prepare build dir
WORKDIR /app

# install hex + rebar
RUN mix local.hex --force && \
    mix local.rebar --force

# set build ENV
ENV MIX_ENV="prod"

# install mix dependencies
COPY ./app1/mix.exs ./app1/mix.lock ./
RUN mix deps.get --only $MIX_ENV
RUN mkdir config

# copy compile-time config files before we compile dependencies
# to ensure any relevant config change will trigger the dependencies
# to be re-compiled.
COPY ./app1/config/config.exs ./app1/config/${MIX_ENV}.exs config/
COPY ./app3 /app3
COPY ./app2 /app2
RUN mix deps.compile

COPY ./app1/priv priv

COPY ./app1/assets assets
# compile assets
RUN mix assets.deploy

# Compile the release
COPY ./app1/lib lib

RUN mix compile

# Changes to config/runtime.exs don't require recompiling the code
COPY ./app1/config/runtime.exs config/

COPY ./app1/rel rel
RUN mix release

# start a new build stage so that the final image will only contain
# the compiled release and other runtime necessities
FROM ${RUNNER_IMAGE}

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libstdc++6 openssl libncurses5 locales \
  && apt-get clean && rm -f /var/lib/apt/lists/*_*

# Set the locale
RUN sed -i '/en_US.UTF-8/s/^# //g' /etc/locale.gen && locale-gen

ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

WORKDIR "/app"
RUN chown nobody /app

# Only copy the final release from the build stage
COPY --from=builder --chown=nobody:root /app/_build/prod/rel/app1 ./

USER nobody

CMD ["/app/bin/server"]

# Appended by flyctl
ENV ECTO_IPV6 true
ENV ERL_AFLAGS "-proto_dist inet6_tcp"
```

The output of `docker build` includes the confirmation that COPY ./app2 /app2 takes place:

```
Step 13/36 : COPY ./app2 /app2
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d1e06c15a7ef
```

That output also ends with confirmation that the image was "Successfully built".

There is no dockerignore file. I do not have a docker-compose.yml or docker-compose.override.yaml file.

In an interactive shell the `/app` directory indeed does not include the app2 assets directory but only `bin erts-12.2 lib releases`. The assets directory or files are not present in any of those subdirectories.

Is this line the problem:

```
# Only copy the final release from the build stage
COPY --from=builder --chown=nobody:root /app/_build/prod/rel/app1 ./
```

When I deploy the container to fly.io the app crashes with the error `(File.Error) could not read file "/app2/assets/words.txt": no such file or directory`. What can I do to get docker to actually copy that file over?

Comment: Are you able to build the image using `docker build` ?

Comment: please show your steps to prove `./app2/assets/words.txt` exists.

Comment: Yes `docker build` runs successfully. I am not sure what you mean Lei Yang. There is no question the file exists in the source at `root/app2/assets/words.txt`. the Dockerfile lives at `root/Dockerfile`.

Comment: do you have dockerignore file? I faced similar issue because of docker igrone file

Comment: Show me docker-compose.yml and docker-compose.override.yml files please.

Comment: in order to COPY file to a specific path, make sure you are using the `RUN mkdir <dir_name>` first and then using the COPY instruction. This will ensure the directory is created and exists before trying to copy the file to a non-existing location.

Comment: @sxddhxrthx If the [Dockerfile `COPY` directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) "... `<dest>` [directory] doesn’t exist, it is created along with all missing directories in its path."  You don't need to `RUN mkdir` for a `COPY` destination (or similarly for the `WORKDIR`).

Comment: The `COPY` syntax can be a little finicky trying to copy directories around.  If you `docker run --rm -it your-image sh` to get an interactive debugging shell on the built image, and you `ls /app2`, what's there?

Comment: First, you should have pasted more steps from your Dockerfile if you asked just with the ```COPY``` command it will be difficult for anyone who is trying to help you.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have edited the question to address all the issues raised in the comments.

Comment: Your WORKDIR is `/app` so I think `app2` gets copied into that folder and it can be found at `/app/app2`